Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive)
There are two remote servers A and B. A sends files to B regularly, connecting through SSH.
Now recently, I got an error -
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive). 
Communication with slave script ends with return code: 255

I ran this command on server A: ssh -v user-of-B@IP-of-B
Here is the output:
userA@serverA:~$ ssh -v userB@IP-of-B
OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3, OpenSSL 3.0.14 4 Jun 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to IP-of-B [IP-of-B] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed26619 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed26619-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed26619_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed26619_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.4* compat 0x04000006
debug1: Authenticating to IP-of-B:22 as 'userB'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: cur26619-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-XXXXXXX
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:TC4xlDHx9aWhXqhHhwWI4EYE3iM0vLzk9M9mdvQRT2c
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host ‘IP-of-B' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:23
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed26619 ED26619 SHA256:1uUlbnUxHgabsZhuMarKd4wAtvWXhQm4ZBJoCUQSluQ
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed26619_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_96278)

debug1: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_96278)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_edXXXXXX XXXXXX SHA256:1uUlbnUxHgabsZhuMarKd4wAtvWXhQm4ZBJoCUQSluQ
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed26619_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
(userB@IP-of-B) Password: 

I ran this command on server B - grep -i "sshd" /var/log/secure
And the outcome is
Nov  9 18:26:04 alpha sshd[21757]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for userB from IP-of-A
Nov  9 18:26:04 alpha sshd[21757]: Postponed keyboard-interactive for userB from IP-of-A port 50664 ssh2 [preauth]
Nov  9 18:26:04 alpha sshd[21783]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP-of-A  user=userB
Nov  9 18:26:05 alpha sshd[21757]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for userB from IP-of-A
Nov  9 18:26:05 alpha sshd[21757]: Connection closed by IP-of-A port 50664 [preauth]

I haven't changed anything regarding the server's SSH keys. It seems like a permission issue, but I can't figure out what's happening.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Can you get the log file from the server as well? If it's sshd that is rejecting the key, then logs from sshd would be much more useful than those from the client.

@grawity - Ok, I will get it. Thank you.

If you don't see any relevant messages, use LogLevel VERBOSE or possibly even LogLevel DEBUG in the server's sshd_config. Might be a client problem but more commonly it's the server.

@grawity - I have updated the post with the logs from /var/logs/secure. It seems like an authentication error, but we haven't changed anything on our server. Is it the directory permission or the .ssh/authorized_key problem?

It's working now. I had to chmod the /home/user directory permission.
